# Firebase Recycler Options is not working: Realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Hi I am trying to query a firebase realtime database for a search function, and use the results to display in a recycler view. I am using firebase recycler adapter and options. The code for the main activity is below:

```
    public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference users;
    Query query;

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options;
     RecyclerView mSearchResult;
    public static final String TAG = "MyActivity";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        mSearchResult = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.usersrecycleview);
        mSearchResult.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mSearchResult.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = database.getReference("users");

        Button mSearchBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);

        mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView searchText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchInput);
                String mSearchText = searchText.getText().toString();

               firebaseUserSearch(mSearchText);

            }
        });

    }


        private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

        query = users;
             
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                      .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                      .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<User>() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public User parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                Log.d(TAG, snapshot.getKey());
                                return snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                            }})
                      .build();


           FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UsersViewHolder>(options) 
            {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, 
                                          @NonNull User model) {
                holder.user_name.setText(model.getUsername());
                Log.v(TAG,model.getUsername());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
              {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.usersrecyclerview_item, parent, false);

                return new UsersViewHolder(view);

            }
        };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        mSearchResult.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
   }
```

My User class is defined here:

public class User {

```
String username;
String password;

public User() {
    //Empty Constructor For Firebase
}


public User(String username, String password)
{
    this.username = username; //Parameterized for Program-Inhouse objects.
    this.password = password;
}

//Getters and Setters
public String getUsername()
{
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username)
{
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword()
{
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password)
{
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

Something is going wrong in the options method call because when I look at the relevant firebase classes, the mSnapshot is returned as null.

The snapshot.getKey() is also not getting logged. But when I call it from outside the options method it is getting logged.

Does anyone have a clue why? This is my database so far:
[Firebase realtime database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtnAy.png)

Comment: By assigning `users` to the `query` object you aren't doing any "search". So what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Whether I do a search or not, the code should work right? When I did a proper query it also didn't work anyway so...